# SQL remove the next letter/character after a character ^

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to remove a character after the character `^` from a selected rows in table?

e.g.

```
TABLE Things 
Boat
Do^2gs
Cat^fs
^KBear
Mi^&ce
D^Rice
```

RESULTS:

```
Boat
Dogs
Cats
Bear
Mice
Dice
```

Comment: **Microsoft SQL Server != MySQL**

Comment: Yeah but I will use on both, MySQL and MSSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  case    when charindex('^', col) <> 0 
        then stuff(col, charindex('^', col), 2, '')
        else col 
        end

-- to handle multiple ^ up to max of 4

select  t.col,
        r4.col
from    Things t
    cross apply
    (
        select  col = case when charindex('^', col) <> 0 
            then stuff(col, charindex('^', col), 2, '')
            else col 
            end
    ) r1
    cross apply
    (
        select  col = case when charindex('^', r1.col) <> 0 
            then stuff(r1.col, charindex('^', r1.col), 2, '')
            else r1.col 
            end
    ) r2
    cross apply
    (
        select  col = case when charindex('^', r2.col) <> 0 
            then stuff(r2.col, charindex('^', r2.col), 2, '')
            else r2.col 
            end
    ) r3
    cross apply
    (
        select  col = case when charindex('^', r3.col) <> 0 
            then stuff(r3.col, charindex('^', r3.col), 2, '')
            else r3.col 
            end
    ) r4

-- UDF to remove the ^
create function remove_chr
(
    @str    varchar(100)
)
returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    while charindex('^', @str) <> 0 
    begin
        select  @str =  case    
                when charindex('^', @str) <> 0 
                then stuff(@str, charindex('^', @str), 2, '')
                else @str 
                end
    end
    return @str
end
```

Comment: can you post the query that you used ?

Comment: nvm Squirrel, it works.. Sorry, I have deleted my previous comment..... Yes it works, but it only works on the first ^ but on the second & other, it does not.... Thanks. But if you have another solution, kindly edit your post. I love to see.

Comment: is there possibly a max number of ^ in the string ?

Comment: In my table, there are only 12 max characters in the string, I allow the user to put multiple ^ up to 4

Comment: added query to handle max 4. Alternatively you can create a scalar function to do that. And in the scalar function , you can use a simple while loop

Comment: added UDF to remove ^

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL` you could use:

```
SELECT col, 
       IF(INSTR(col,'^') > 0,CONCAT(LEFT(col,INSTR(col, '^')-1),
          RIGHT(col,LENGTH(col) - INSTR(col, '^')-1)), col) AS result
FROM Things;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f29d4/12/0)**</kbd>

And `SQL Server` equivalent:

```
SELECT col, 
       IIF(CHARINDEX('^',col) > 0,CONCAT(LEFT(col,CHARINDEX('^',col)-1),
              RIGHT(col,LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('^',col)-1)), col) AS result
FROM Things
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/VGV7414)**</kbd>

---

`SQL Server 2008`:

```
SELECT col, 
  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('^',col) > 0 
    THEN LEFT(col,CHARINDEX('^',col)-1) + RIGHT(col,LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('^',col)-1)
    ELSE col
  END AS result
FROM Things;
```

Keep in mind that it will work only if there is none or one occurence of `^`.

Comment: THANKS. I love it, it is all there, MySQL, SQL, and SQL2008

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which removes any number of occurrence of '^' .
I have created a function SQL server which is not used any loop or cursor.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[FnReplaceChar](@pOriginalText VARCHAR(2000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @vText VARCHAR(1000)
                ,@vXML XML

        --Convert text as XML format
        SELECT @vXML = '<Root><dtl><f>' + REPLACE(@pOriginalText,'^','</f></dtl><dtl><f>^')+'</f></dtl></Root>'

        --Splits words started with '^' and combines after removing character starts with '^'
        SET @vText = (
                        SELECT  '' + ACT_TEXT
                        FROM
                        (
                        SELECT  CASE    WHEN CHARINDEX('^',DOC.COL.value('f[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ,0) > 0
                                        THEN STUFF(DOC.COL.value('f[1]','VARCHAR(100)'),CHARINDEX('^',DOC.COL.value('f[1]','VARCHAR(100)') ,0),2,'')
                                        ELSE DOC.COL.value('f[1]','VARCHAR(100)')
                                END AS ACT_TEXT
                        FROM    @vXML.nodes('/Root/dtl') DOC(COL)
                        )T
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    )

        RETURN @vText
END
```

You can use this function in your select query

```
SELECT dbo.[FnReplaceChar](col_Name) 
FROM [Things]
```